# Most reliable way to detect when element overflows print width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<table>` where users customize the number of elements, font, and font size, and users often print the table.  If the table is too wide to fit on a single printed page, some columns get cut off and the user may not realize until later, at which point the user is upset.

Is there a good way to detect when the table overflows the print width so I can warn the user?  I know that the proper answer is "web browsers were not designed for printing, you can't do that", so I'm happy with a hack.  Right now I use jQuery `outerWidth()` to see if the width is greater than 700px.  Is there a better way?

Comment: You're probably best to use a specific stylesheet for `media="print"` and use that to set all widths to `%` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a `media print` css style sheet where you specify the max width of the table, and make sure that you use `table-layout:fixed;`. Additionally you can set word-wrap in such a way that everything breaks nicely when you deal with large input.

```
@media print {
    html{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 700px;
    }
    .toprinttable {
        font-size: 11px;
        max-width: 700px;
        border: 0;
        table-layout:fixed; /*This is important*/
        word-wrap:break-word;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet.  Hadn't seen `table-layout` before.